# Kubernetes api server does not run on coreos?

Tags: kubernetes, coreos

I have started installing kubernetes on coreos . But kubernetes api does not run on port 8080. Unable to proceed. It stops at the command curl --silent http://127.0.0.1:8080 and goes to sleep.

Comment: Can you paste kube-apiserver's manifest in your question? It should be at `/etc/kubernetes/manifests/kube-apiserver.yaml`. Also, can you describe how you installed k8s in the node?

Answer (score 0):

kubernetes api servers running on port 6443. try curl with this port.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the deployment script you used, it may not be running on port 8080. Check the `kube-apiserver` manifest on the k8s node which is usually at `/etc/kubernetes/manifests/kube-apiserver.yaml`. `kube-apiserver` should be started with the flag `--insecure-port=8080`. If it's `--insecure-port=0`, the insecure port is disabled.

Also, use `curl -v http://127.0.0.1:8080` and post the results here. Like what @sfgroups said, try `curl -v http://127.0.0.1:6443`.

Comment: output for curl -v http://127.0.0.1:6443

core@localhost ~ $ curl -v http://127.0.0.1:6443
* Rebuilt URL to: http://127.0.0.1:6443/
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* connect to 127.0.0.1 port 6443 failed: Connection refused
* Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 6443: Connection refused
* Closing connection 0
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 6443: Connection refused

Comment: Thanks for the reply :)